# nodejs; drop into Nth in a series of dependent functions

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, series

Let's say you have a series of functions that need to be executed in-order, during initialization, but depending on circumstances, you might start on any one of them.  If not for the async nature of node, this would be easy with a simple switch statement where each case falls through to the next; however, each of the functions does do I/O (database hits).

Blocking language/framework would look like this:

```
switch ( entry_point )
    {
    case 0:
        function_zero( blah );
    case 1:
        function_one( blah );
    case 2:
        function_two( blah );
    [.... up to case N ....]
    default: 
        wrap_up();
    }
```

I feel like there's probably a good way to do this with async, but I'm not seeing anything elegant.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all functions are in order, you could add all of your functions to an array:

```
var functions = [function_zero, function_one, function_two, wrap_up];
```

and then execute them with for example the `async` module as follows:

```
async.series(functions);
```

The benefint of adding them to an array is that you could slice the array to begin in the middle like so:

```
async.series(functions.slice(entry_point));
```

A complete example:

```
var async = require('async');

function function_zero(next) {
    console.log('zero');
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('zero done');
        next(null);
    }, 200);
}

function function_one(next) {
    console.log('one');
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('one done');
        next(null);
    }, 200);
}

function function_two(next) {
    console.log('two');
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('two done');
        next(null);
    }, 200);
}

function wrap_up(next) {
    console.log('wrap up');
    next();
}

var functions = [function_zero, function_one, function_two, wrap_up];


async.series(functions.slice(1));
```

Output:

```
one
one done
two
two done
wrap up
```

Of course this solution is very specific to this case, but often Javascript's ability to handle functions as variables allows you to do some clever things.

Comment: Ha, I knew there was something reasonably elegant; I just hadn't married those two ideas together.  Perfect answer, nice example, well done.  Thanks.